# Unknown Source of MSIX-IRQ once every 2s

Tags: networking, performance, monitoring

I have an Ubuntu PC with an Intel i210 NIC with a port named enp1s0. It has no IP address assigned. The port is connected to another port with an I210 on a similar Ubuntu PC and that port also has no IP address assigned. DHCP is disabled on both ports and MDNS is off (avahi daemon).

1. Driver igb version:  6.2.0-31-generic
2. firmware-version: 3.25, 0x800006eb, 1.1824.0

I see an IRQ on the port per tx-rx queue once every 2s which I cannot find the root cause of.
I have a script that outputs `/proc/interrupts` with an interval of 10 seconds and the output is:

```
31:          0          0          0          1  IR-PCI-MSIX-0000:01:00.0   0-edge      enp1s0
 32:          7          0          0       1375  IR-PCI-MSIX-0000:01:00.0   1-edge      enp1s0-TxRx-0
 33:       1420          8          0          0  IR-PCI-MSIX-0000:01:00.0   2-edge      enp1s0-TxRx-1
 34:          0          0       1653          0  IR-PCI-MSIX-0000:01:00.0   3-edge      enp1s0-TxRx-2
 35:          0          0       1518         11  IR-PCI-MSIX-0000:01:00.0   4-edge      enp1s0-TxRx-3

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 31:          0          0          0          1  IR-PCI-MSIX-0000:01:00.0   0-edge      enp1s0
 32:          7          0          0       1380  IR-PCI-MSIX-0000:01:00.0   1-edge      enp1s0-TxRx-0
 33:       1425          8          0          0  IR-PCI-MSIX-0000:01:00.0   2-edge      enp1s0-TxRx-1
 34:          0          0       1658          0  IR-PCI-MSIX-0000:01:00.0   3-edge      enp1s0-TxRx-2
 35:          0          0       1523         11  IR-PCI-MSIX-0000:01:00.0   4-edge      enp1s0-TxRx-3
```

Now, I am **not** sending or receiving any data on this port. I verfiy this with tcpdump.

Monitoring the statistics of the port with Ethtool. These did not change over the 10s period where i received 5 IRQs per tx-rx-queue.

```
ethtool -S enp1s0 | grep rx
     rx_packets: 0
     rx_bytes: 0
     rx_broadcast: 0
     rx_multicast: 0
     rx_crc_errors: 0
     rx_no_buffer_count: 0
     rx_missed_errors: 0
     rx_long_length_errors: 0
     rx_short_length_errors: 0
     rx_align_errors: 0
     rx_flow_control_xon: 0
     rx_flow_control_xoff: 0
     rx_long_byte_count: 0
     rx_smbus: 0
     os2bmc_rx_by_bmc: 0
     os2bmc_rx_by_host: 0
     rx_hwtstamp_cleared: 0
     rx_errors: 0
     rx_length_errors: 0
     rx_over_errors: 0
     rx_frame_errors: 0
     rx_fifo_errors: 0
     rx_queue_0_packets: 0
     rx_queue_0_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_0_drops: 0
     rx_queue_0_csum_err: 0
     rx_queue_0_alloc_failed: 0
     rx_queue_1_packets: 0
     rx_queue_1_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_1_drops: 0
     rx_queue_1_csum_err: 0
     rx_queue_1_alloc_failed: 0
     rx_queue_2_packets: 0
     rx_queue_2_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_2_drops: 0
     rx_queue_2_csum_err: 0
     rx_queue_2_alloc_failed: 0
     rx_queue_3_packets: 0
     rx_queue_3_bytes: 0
     rx_queue_3_drops: 0
     rx_queue_3_csum_err: 0
     rx_queue_3_alloc_failed: 0
```

However the received packet still triggers a NAPI poll:

I see a NAPI poll action on all CPUs once every 2 seconds. This suggests that the driver is calling a NAPI schedule once every 2s.

`sudo trace-cmd record -e napi:napi_poll`

wait for a bit and then:

`sudo trace-cmd report -t | grep enp1s0`

```
kworker/3:0-36    [003]  1571.355236183: napi_poll:            napi poll on napi struct 0xffffa09b91c4d050 for device enp1s0 work 0 budget 64
          <idle>-0     [000]  1571.355249600: napi_poll:            napi poll on napi struct 0xffffa09b91c49050 for device enp1s0 work 0 budget 64
          <idle>-0     [002]  1571.355250331: napi_poll:            napi poll on napi struct 0xffffa09b91c4a050 for device enp1s0 work 0 budget 64
          <idle>-0     [002]  1571.355250909: napi_poll:            napi poll on napi struct 0xffffa09b91c4f050 for device enp1s0 work 0 budget 64
     kworker/3:0-36    [003]  1573.371205650: napi_poll:            napi poll on napi struct 0xffffa09b91c4d050 for device enp1s0 work 0 budget 64
          <idle>-0     [002]  1573.371218257: napi_poll:            napi poll on napi struct 0xffffa09b91c4a050 for device enp1s0 work 0 budget 64
          <idle>-0     [002]  1573.371219336: napi_poll:            napi poll on napi struct 0xffffa09b91c4f050 for device enp1s0 work 0 budget 64
          <idle>-0     [000]  1573.371224475: napi_poll:            napi poll on napi struct 0xffffa09b91c49050 for device enp1s0 work 0 budget 64
     kworker/3:0-36    [003]  1575.355151221: napi_poll:            napi poll on napi struct 0xffffa09b91c4d050 for device enp1s0 work 0 budget 64
          <idle>-0     [000]  1575.355163970: napi_poll:            napi poll on napi struct 0xffffa09b91c49050 for device enp1s0 work 0 budget 64
          <idle>-0     [002]  1575.355165554: napi_poll:            napi poll on napi struct 0xffffa09b91c4a050 for device enp1s0 work 0 budget 64
          <idle>-0     [002]  1575.355166268: napi_poll:            napi poll on napi struct 0xffffa09b91c4f050 for device enp1s0 work 0 budget 64
     kworker/3:0-36    [003]  1577.371105686: napi_poll:            napi poll on napi struct 0xffffa09b91c4d050 for device enp1s0 work 0 budget 64
          <idle>-0     [002]  1577.371119014: napi_poll:            napi poll on napi struct 0xffffa09b91c4a050 for device enp1s0 work 0 budget 64
          <idle>-0     [002]  1577.371119537: napi_poll:            napi poll on napi struct 0xffffa09b91c4f050 for device enp1s0 work 0 budget 64
          <idle>-0     [000]  1577.371152808: napi_poll:            napi poll on napi struct 0xffffa09b91c49050 for device enp1s0 work 0 budget 64
     kworker/3:0-36    [003]  1579.355064065: napi_poll:            napi poll on napi struct 0xffffa09b91c4d050 for device enp1s0 work 0 budget 64
          <idle>-0     [002]  1579.355077379: napi_poll:            napi poll on napi struct 0xffffa09b91c4a050 for device enp1s0 work 0 budget 64
          <idle>-0     [002]  1579.355077852: napi_poll:            napi poll on napi struct 0xffffa09b91c4f050 for device enp1s0 work 0 budget 64
          <idle>-0     [000]  1579.355111058: napi_poll:            napi poll on napi struct 0xffffa09b91c49050 for device enp1s0 work 0 budget 64
```

Comment: Could be the hardware polling the driver with cable connection status information.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do you know how I can check if this is the case?

Comment: Was more a guess than anything, could also be ARP requests or keepalive packets from the router. Might be worth firing up wires hark and seeing if there is something that corresponds.

Comment: Nothing pops up on wireshark or tcpdump. There is also no router in the network. This port is connected to just another port on another Ubuntu PC with the same settings.

Comment: I wound a watchdog task that looks suspicious.https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/igb/igb_main.c#L5511